# firebase.functions() is undefined in React while firebase.firestore() can work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, I'm working on a React project which uses Firebase to achieve lots of functionalities.
And now I'm trying to use some HTTPS callable functions in it.

But it seems like the way I import the 'firebase/functions' module is not correct. And it's giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'httpsCallable' of undefined
```

Below is how I do the import and set up:

```js
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';

const config = {
   // the config info here
};

  class Firebase {
    constructor() {
      app.initializeApp(config);
      this.auth = app.auth();
      this.db = app.firestore();
      this.functions = app.functions();
    }

    // trying to call the function
    doCreatePlanner = this.functions.httpsCallable('createPlanner')
```

After applying Doug's advice:

> You are trying to access this.functions before you defined it in the constructor. To get rid of the error message, you could move the call to httpsCallable into the constructor:

I did this:

```js
class  Firebase {
    constructor() {
        app.initializeApp(config);
        this.auth = app.auth();
        this.db = app.firestore();
        // Get the callable function reference here
        this.createPlannerCloudFunc = app.functions().httpsCallable('createPlanner')
    }
    
    doCreatePlanner = (input) =>  this.createPlannerCloudFunc(input)
```

And it works!

But I am still a little confused.

Shouldn't constructor always be called first when a class is created/used?

So in the doCreatePlanner function, `this.functions` should hold `app.functions()`, right?

I can do function like this in the class, where `this.db` holds `app.firestore()` :

```js
doUpdateRecord = (userRecord) =>
    // create the user in firestore
    this.db.collection(`users`).doc(userRecord.uid).set({
        // record info here
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference `this.functions = app.functions()` is pointing to a collection of objects. The pointer doesn't hold the function because the type of these objects are not the same. In one hand you have a single entity, and in the other you have a list of objects.

The `this.db` can hold `app.firestore()` because the type of these properties is the same.